# SapUI5 NodeJS ECONNREFUSED in VSCode when running local server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sapui5, ui5-tooling

I working in a Microsoft Axure VM with a proxy behind. Proxy is setted up as it would not possible to install npm packages.

Now when running ui5.yaml with npm run start I got this error while localhost is started:

```
Server started
URL: http://localhost:8080
ApplicationInsights:CorrelationIdManager [
  Error: connect ECONNREFUSED xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1595:16) {
    errno: -4078,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
    port: 443
  }
]
```

[local server error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvOcG.png)

We added IP and port also to firewall but it does not help.
Also removed proxy settings but no change of error.

This is also my
[ui5.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gFxn.png).

Has somebody a good idea what I missed?

Comment: what are the instructions behind start task on your package.json ?
+ what is the problem ? did you access your app trought http://localhost:8080 ?